# How to remove Ctrl-M from files where dos2unix, perl, tr, and sed are not present?

Tags: command-line, software-rec

Suppose you are working on a very old unix server where `dos2unix`, `perl`, `tr`, and `sed` are not present. How can you convert files from *dos* to *unix* format?

Comment: sed is allowed?

Comment: @elmarco:  no :(

Comment: I am trying using vi but no luck till now

Comment: How old does a unix server have to be to not have `tr` and `sed` ? `sed` is old........ iirc,

Comment: Is there a C complier? :)

Comment: Would `ex` or `ed` be available on a system like that? I would'nt call it *unix* if there is no `tr` or `sed`.

Comment: No `sed`?  Really!?  Out of interest, what is the system?  As Gilles and MattBianco point out, it would probably still have `ed` at least.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are referring to removing the caret-M at the end of lines.  You can use search and replace in vi to do this.

In vi I normally do: (where "^" represents CTRL):

```
:%s/^V^M//g
```

Which shows on the screen as:

```
:%s/^M//g
```

Comment: thanks that worked :).
I think its a very portable solution.

Comment: You can also use sed to do the same thing w/out having to vim the file:  sed -e '%s/^V^M//g' filename  
That also will show on the screen as sed e '%s/^M//g' filename
In general, if you can search/replace it in vim, the command is virtually the same in sed.

Comment: @gabe: the sed solution is actually even more portable +1 :)

Comment: @wzzrd, `sed` and `vi` are both [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), and that `vi` command doesn't use any Vim extensions.

Comment: @jjclarkson what does `^V` and '^M' mean?

Comment: @gabe. is my sed to old to do this  `$ sed -e '%s/^M//g' cookies
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `%'
`   ?

Answer (score 6):

A server without `tr` or `sed` would have to be really old, or missing some basic commands. Hopefully `ed` is there; it existed in [Unix first edition](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/ed).

```
ed /path/to/file
1,$s/^V^M$//
w
q
```

where `^V^M` means typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (to enter a literal line feed). If you know that all lines do end in CR LF, you can use `1,$s/.$//` instead (indiscriminately remove the last character on each line).