# AWK weird output behavior when adding extra column

Tags: awk

I have a file.csv that contains:

```
ID,FN,LN,NUM
576,Pra,Mar,3
688,India,Desa,3
645,Ami,Path,5
245,Me,Yo,4
```

When I try to print all column fields, it works fine

> awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' FS=, OFS=, file.csv

```
ID,FN,LN,NUM
576,Pra,Mar,3
688,India,Desa,3
645,Ami,Path,5
245,Me,Yo,4
```

But if I try to add an extra column to the end, it won't work

> awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,"R"}' FS=, OFS=, file.csv

```
,R,FN,LN,NUM
,R576,Pra,Mar,3
,R688,India,Desa,3
,R645,Ami,Path,5
245,Me,Yo,4,R
```

I want the output to be

```
ID,FN,LN,NUM,R
576,Pra,Mar,3,R
688,India,Desa,3,R
645,Ami,Path,5,R
245,Me,Yo,4,R
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5):

If your input file has carriage-return/line-feed endings it will do that.

Here is what that looks like in vi (you may need list-mode for clarity):

```
Wed Mar 30 18:53:01 EDT 2016
ID,FN,LN,NUM^M
576,Pra,Mar,3^M
688,India,Desa,3^M
645,Ami,Path,5^M
245,Me,Yo,4^M
Wed Mar 30 18:53:01 EDT 2016
ID,FN,LN,NUM^M,R
576,Pra,Mar,3^M,R
688,India,Desa,3^M,R
645,Ami,Path,5^M,R
245,Me,Yo,4^M,R
```

In the second example, the `^M` characters precede the ",R", making that print at the beginning of the line.

If you view this in *vim* rather than *vi*, you will see something similar.

You can convert line-endings in different ways:

- in *vim*, if you type <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, you will notice a "[dos]" in the status line, and then by typing ":set" (enter) see "dos" in the output.  You can convert by

```
    :set ff=unix
    :w!
```

- on the command-line, you may have `dos2unix` (that works as well).

Further reading:

- [What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it/32020#32020)
- [How to remove Ctrl-M from files where dos2unix, perl, tr, and sed are not present?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411/how-to-remove-ctrl-m-from-files-where-dos2unix-perl-tr-and-sed-are-not-presen)

Comment: This is what my input file look like with list-modem, it has $ instead of ^M
576,Pra,Mar,3$

Comment: vi and vim do different things.