# Convert file with Windows-style EOL to Unix-style EOL without using dos2unix

Tags: conversion

I use an old server without `dos2unix` and I would like to convert files containing Windows-style end-of-line (EOL) to Unix-style EOL. I am unfortunately not the admin so I can't install `dos2unix`. The `tr` method seems to be the only one that works.

```
cp script _p4 && tr -d '\r' < _p4 > script && rm _p4
```

Are there any easier methods to do this?

Comment: `dos2unix` is a small and relatively self-contained binary. There's a sporting chance it will work on your server. If you have `dos2unix` installed on a machine with the same arch and OS (is this Linux?) then try copying it to your home directory and do `./dos2unix file_you_want_to_convert`. Or, of course you could just download a suitable binary to the server directly.

Answer (score 14):

If you have GNU sed you can do this:

```
sed -i 's/\x0D$//' script
```

Where "x0D" is the ASCII code for \r.

Comment: `\r` is supported by `sed`, too. Why use harder-to-remember number when you can use simpler notation?

Comment: I used to think that \r was not supported by all sed version, especially the GNU one. Things have changed, but I still use something which can be more portable to all sed version (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: @gapz any idea why this one won't work `sed -e '%s/^M//g' cookies
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `%'
`  ? Is my sed to old?

Comment: What are you trying to do with "%" ? Your are not in vim ;-).

Comment: Saw that on another page http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411/how-to-remove-ctrl-m-from-files-where-dos2unix-perl-tr-and-sed-are-not-presen. Couldn't get it to work so I asked my question here.

Comment: "%" means "the whole text" in vim. If you want to do this with sed, just type "s/^M//g" (to get ^M if you to type CTRL+V then CTRL+M).

Comment: I wasn't able to get the \x0D to work with busybox sed.  However \r did work with busybox sed.

Comment: The busybox sed version I have is
```sed --version                                                  
This is not GNU sed version 4.0```

Answer (score 5):

You can always write a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for name in "$@"
do
    cp "$name" "$name"~ && tr -d '\r' < "$name"~ > "$name" && rm "$name"~
done
```

and name that `dos2unix`.  No compiler is needed.

Answer (score 4):

This command can be used to convert EOL characters without having dos2unix installed:

```
sed -i 's/.$//' script
```

Comment: Note that if you run this on a Linux-style EOL file, this answer will effectively destroy it (the sed command simply strips off all last characters). This behaviour is different from the `dos2unix` tool which ignores files that don't contain Windows-style line endings.