# Converting Windows line breaks in scripts without using dos2unix

Tags: linux, conversion

I have shell scripts that could or could not contain Windows line breaks. I want to convert all existing Windows line breaks to Unix-style, and not destroy the file in the process. I used `dos2unix` on my development server, but I found out that it’s not installed on the production server, and I cannot install it there. I have to find an alternative that does the exact same thing as `dos2unix`. In particular, I need the result to have the same attributes as the original file: if the file was executable before conversion, it must be executable afterwards.

Comment: I would expect that `col` command, with those specific redirections, to erase most of the data in the file pointed to by `$path`.  Additionally, if the current shell is `zsh`, the `path` variable is special (an array containing the paths listed in `$PATH`), so if you changed its value, `col` may not be found at all (that goes for the `dos2unix` command as well, obviously)

Comment: So is there no alternative to "dos2unix" that does the exact same thing. Nothing more, nothing less? Every other Command i read about( here too ) returns not the same result.

Comment: @Jules of course there's alternatives. But it's impossible to know what you have at hand. All that's being said here is that, to little surprise, `col` is not the tool.

Comment: There's also `busybox dos2unix` if your system has `busybox`.

Comment: @Jules, "_I found out that its not installed on the production server. And I cannot install it._" - the usual approach here is that you go to your Change Board and give reasons for it to get installed. Don't work around a situation when the proper solution is to fix it. (And that might be fixing the scripts in development, not working around broken line-endings on production.)

Comment: Sounds *a lot* like you would be much better off fixing your scripts on a development machine.

Comment: Also, if you deploy to a "production server", that means your self-written scripts *are* already in a source control system; so... that is probably already possible.

Comment: Jules it's helpful in the sense that you should address the underlying issue with your development environment. Then you won't need `dos2unix` or any other conversion solution on your production system because it's already fixed _before_ it gets to production.

Comment: The "solution" seems like commands that do more than dos2unix. And obviously i'm developing on a dev machine. I dont understand comments like this. Not helpful

Comment: @Jules The comments are saying that you should be deploying corrected scripts to the production system, instead of modifying the scripts with `dos2unix` on the production system before running them, which would introduce unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Use the script suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32059/100397), @Jules. The command that does the work is `tr`.

Comment: @roaima thanks i'll look into it

Comment: @Jules you got very detailed expert answers. Please try to understand that the solution to the problem "I have a production server on which I want to fix scripts" is, no matter whether you have dos2unix or any other tool on that server, "so go and fix your scripts on your developer laptop/PC/whatever, and deploy." It's not a production server if the approach to scripts is that you fix them on the server.

Comment: All answers in the other post don't do the same. dos2unix only changes the file if there are windows line breaks. So my question was not answered.  FYI.

Thanks to the people who tried to help without being condescending.

Comment: Heres the function i use in my script:
`copyAllFiles() {
 replaceStr="/var/"
 searchStr="/home/"
 echo "copying files from: $1"
 for f in "$1"/*
 do
  if [ -d $f ]
  then
   copyAllFiles $f
  else  
   filename=$(basename -- "$f")
   extension="${filename##*.}"
   
   newPath=$(echo "$f" | sed "s#/home/jwe/#/var/#g")
   echo "Copy $f to $newPath"
   cp "$f" "$newPath"
   
   if [ "$extension" = "sh" ] 
   then 
    echo "Convert shell script to Unix $newPath"
    dos2unix $newPath
   fi
  fi
 done
}`

Comment: The `sed` command [given here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279865/86440) will preserve the executable bit.

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks i'll try that command

Comment: @StephenKitt thanks a lot. That seems to work!

Comment: @Jules Please keep this site's [Code of Conduct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/conduct) in mind when interacting with others on this site. Some of your recent comments have cross the line and have been deleted. Thank you.