# Enter IP at the end of a specific line

Tags: linux, text-processing, scripting, ip-address

I have the following file.txt that follows the same pattern and I want to modify it where this file is by adding an ip:

```
# gfhfhgfh
gfhfghgfhgfhgfh
MACs 
# access
USER CONSOLA *,!10.249.247.3,!10.249.245.65
/bin/false
```

I want to add an ip in the end of the line that contains as patron USER CONSOLE:

```
 USER CONSOLA *,!10.249.247.4,!10.249.245.65,!10.249.245.90,
```

I only manage to add the ip in the whole document at the moment but not in that particular line the code used is

```
sed 's/\r\?$/,!10.10.11.1/' file.txt
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and spell the string consistently.

Comment: I'm using this command that really does what I want: `sed -i /USER CONSOLA/s/\r/-------/' file.txt`  but now inside the text I see all the lines at the end with ^ M

Comment: The `^M` sequence likely indicates that your file has Windows line endings - you can remove them with `dos2unix` or see for example [How to remove Ctrl-M from files where dos2unix, perl, tr, and sed are not present?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411/how-to-remove-ctrl-m-from-files-where-dos2unix-perl-tr-and-sed-are-not-presen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match at the start of the line (`^` anchor) and substitute the new text at the end of the line (`$` anchor):

```
$ sed '/^USER CONSOLA/ s/$/,!10.10.11.1/' file.txt
# gfhfhgfh
gfhfghgfhgfhgfh
MACs 
# access
USER CONSOLA *,!10.249.247.3,!10.249.245.65,!10.10.11.1
/bin/false
```

---

If your file has Windows/DOS style CRLF line endings that you wish to preserve, modify the above to

```
sed '/^USER CONSOLA/ s/\r$/,!10.10.11.1\r/' file.txt
```

If you *don't* wish to preserve the DOS endings, then either remove them first with `dos2unix` or by adding an additional command to do that in sed:

```
sed -e 's/\r$//' -e '/^USER CONSOLA/ s/$/,!10.10.11.1/' file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Used below method to achieve same

```
sed  "/USER CONSOLA/s/.*/&\,\!10.249.245.90,/g" filename
```

output

```
# gfhfhgfh
gfhfghgfhgfhgfh
MACs
# access
USER CONSOLA *,!10.249.247.3,!10.249.245.65,!10.249.245.90,
/bin/false
```